# Why onDestroy doesn't kill its methods?

Tags: android, android-lifecycle, asmack

I am working on xmpp chat on Android now. I have next situation:
1) I have singletone class with XMPPConnection and 2 activities.
2) 1st activity is just a list of contacts, which I can choose and start message with.
3) In second activity(chat) I setup listeners for my connection and add some signal, which plays, when message from particular contact is received.
4) Then I close chat activity and onDestroy method is called.
5) And then, if I message to my app - I hear the signal, which plays in destroyed activity(I mean method which plays signal must be destroyed with chat activity).

Please, explain me why it's possible.

```
    public class ChatActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
    ...
    public void beep() {
            Uri notification = RingtoneManager
                    .getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
            RingtoneManager.getRingtone(getApplicationContext(), notification).play();
        }
    ...

    public void setupListeners(XMPPConnection connection) {
            if(connection != null) {
                //Set a listener for chat messages
                connection.addPacketListener(new PacketListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void processPacket(Packet packet) {
                        Message message = (Message) packet;
                        if (message.getBody() != null && message.getFrom()
                                .contains(chatModel.getRecipient())) {
                            chatModel.addMessage(StringUtils.parseBareAddress(message.getFrom())
                                    + " :" + message.getBody());
                            beep();
                        }
                    }
                }, new MessageTypeFilter(Message.Type.chat));

                //Set a listener for normal messages
                connection.addPacketListener(new PacketListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void processPacket(Packet packet) {
                        Message message = (Message) packet;
                        if(message.getBody() != null && message.getFrom()
                                .contains(chatModel.getRecipient())) {
                            chatModel.addMessage(StringUtils.parseBareAddress(message.getFrom())
                                    + " :" + message.getBody());
                            beep();
                        }
                    }
                }, new MessageTypeFilter(Message.Type.normal));
       }
   }
```

Comment: Have you actually verified that the "destroyed" class is being destroyed as you think it is? It is possible that your class is still active because there are references to it that prevent it from being destroyed. You should use MAT to check this. A workaround while you're looking into this would be to use a conditional and a boolean set when onDestroy is called. This way when your activity is "destroyed" you could stop the methods from being called even if the class persists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried disconnecting the Connection in the onDestroy of your Activity? Or to remove the listeners? 
Because of these inner classes, which hold a (hidden) reference to their outer class - your Activity in this case, the Activity possibly can't be garbage collected. So removing the listeners or disconnecting the Connection should do the trick.

Edit: Like Gusdor said, you'd want to remove the listeners in the onPause() Method and add them again in the onResume().

Edit2: If you want that the XMPP Connection runs in the background, you should consider using a background Service for handling the Connection and the messages, instead of the Activity.

Comment: If you want to be super conformant, google would recommend disconnecting when the activity is paused.

Comment: Yup, you're right. And for something like a chat, you'd maybe want use a background Service for the Connection and not an Activity, so that it can run even if the Activity gets closed.

Comment: You were right, I delete and then add listeners - now, all are fine.

Answer (score 2):

`Objects` in Java are not immediately destroyed when you quit the `Activity`. Also, you  cannot manually call for the garbage collector. What you could do is nullify the objects in the `onDestroy()` method:

```
connection = null;
```